# Colorizing Images on Hover Using CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I am wondering if it is possible to recolour images using CSS.

Here is an example fragment showing what I want to do (you can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/NPmUX/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="upgrade_link cannons"><strong>Autoblaster (5)</strong><br>
Attack: Attack 1 ship. Your <img title="hit" class="inline_action_icon" src="http://xwing-builder.co.uk/images/hit_icon.png"> results cannot be cancelled by defense dice. The defender may cancel <img title="critical" class="inline_action_icon" src="http://xwing-builder.co.uk/images/critical_icon.png"> results before <img title="hit" class="inline_action_icon" src="http://xwing-builder.co.uk/images/hit_icon.png"> results. Attack value: 3. Range 1.</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.upgrade_link {
    background-position: 0 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding-left: 28px;
    transition: color 0.2s ease 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.upgrade_link.cannons {
    background-image: url("http://xwing-builder.co.uk/images/cannon_icon_lg.png");
}

.inline_action_icon {
    margin-top: -2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.upgrade_link:hover {
    color: #597690;
}
```

The link tag contains inline and background images. When rolled over, the text changes colour. Is it possible to also change the colour of either image type?

I have been playing about with [CSS3 Filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) (in Chrome - other browsers don't support them yet) but hue-rotate doesn't work (presumably because the images are monochrome to start with).

Is there a way to colorize the images either with filters or by another technique?

*(Obviously I could just create lots of differently-coloured image files in Photoshop... I am hoping for a programmatic solution)*

Thank you

Comment: If you created a font with the icons, then you could simply change the `color: #f00;` on hover. Google creating icon fonts for info.

Comment: maybe sprites are an option in your case?

Comment: One way to make filters work is to have the image colored, and then turn it black applying a filter in the base state.

Answer (score 3):

One trick I use make the image and actual mask, so the icon is transparent and the border is white (or whatever the background is).

Wrap the image in a div (or set it as the background of a div)

Then you can change the background color of the wrapping div to whatever you like, just like the text and the icon will be that color.

This solution only works on a solid color background.

Comment: I've used this technique before, and OP, it's probably going to be your best option. Make a mask of the icon, where you cut out (transparent PNG) the dynamically-colored areas, so that the element's dynamic background-color (that you animate) shows through.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SVGs and change the colors in CSS.

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
circle {
  fill: black;
}
circle:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/yayojeboku/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've researched this extensively and you said you've been messing around with filters, so it wouldn't surprise me if you already know you can change an image color hue, saturation, grayscale, etc with webkit filters. Which by definition, it colorizing

```
.saturate {-webkit-filter: saturate(5);}
.grayscale {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);}
.contrast {-webkit-filter: contrast(160%);}
.sepia {-webkit-filter: sepia(100%);}
.huerotate {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);}
.rss.opacity {-webkit-filter: opacity(50%);}
```

[***DEMO HERE***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cyreg/)

Comment: does this work on the *monochrome* image of the OP? have you tried it yet?

Comment: hmmm, I just went back and read that. You are right, it wont work on monochromatic images...I did find a a tool that would colorize a monochromatic image, but I'm betting is done with JQuery. [SEE HERE](http://manytools.org/image/colorize-filter/)

Comment: @KingKing It can work if you change the states. That is, make the image blue, and apply a filter to turn it black in the normal state (grayscale + contrast, I guess). On hover, set the filter to none.

Comment: MAking it coloured and monochromaticizing it as a default would work... but the filters aren't widely supported yet so too many users would get the coloured version. Shame.

Comment: @LOTUSMS - Your link helped me solve the problem. Looking at the source, I followed a trail of scripts on Github and elsewhere and ended up finding CamanJS which works perfectly.

Comment: @voidstate Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you use an iconic font, you can then handle it just as text.

Well, it **is** text.

A search for *CSS icon font* will get you a lot of resources.

One good resource to begin with is [fontello](http://fontello.com/)

The easy way is to choose an icon from the already provided in different libraries.

Else, there is the posibility to draw it using vector tools

Comment: This would be a great solution. Unfortunately, the icons are very specific to the web app (its for a Star Wars minis game) and I only have them as bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

**if possible**

use .farbtastic jquery

html

```
 <div id="colorpicker"></div>
<img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/6rt5sj.png" border="0">
```

jquery

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function(color){
    $('img').css("background-color",color);
});
```

css color

```
img{background-color:red;}
```